# I can't display the list correctly

Tags: python-3.x

```
list2 = []
q = int(input("Quantos contatos deseja adicionar? "))
for i in range(q):
    list1 = []
    nome = list1.append(input("Nome: "))
    num = list1.append(input("Número: "))
    list2.append(list1)

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

For example I want list1 to be

```
['abc', '123', 'def', '456', 'ghi', '789']
```

and list 2

```
[['abc', '123'], ['def', '456'], ['ghi', '789']]
```

However it prints

```
['ghi', '789']

[['abc', '123'], ['def', '456'], ['ghi', '789']]

And if I put outside the range it prints

['abc', '123', 'def', '456', 'ghi', '789']

[['abc', '123', 'def', '456', 'ghi', '789'], ['abc', '123', 'def', '456', 'ghi', '789'], ['abc', '123', 'def', '456', 'ghi', '789']]
```

Why is it overwriting the first 2 elements?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** It is overwriting the first 2 elements because you are resetting it each time in the for loop by executing `list1 = []`.

**How-to:** This is a necessity given that `list1` is an input and if you want to append it to `list2` it has to be the new one. I'd suggest creating a new variable as it is logically incompatible to try to get `list1` to do both. I'm using `list_entry` below to achieve what you want to append to `list2`. `list1` will print as you wish.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
q = int(input("Quantos contatos deseja adicionar? "))
for i in range(q):
    nome = input("Nome: ")
    num = input("Número: ")
    list1.append(nome)
    list1.append(num)
    list2.append([nome, num])

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

On a further note `nome` and `num` were returning empty as the append function is reflexive and operates on the object it's attached to without returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because list1 is inside the loop and gets set to null with each iteration.

I tried this and it produced the result you were looking for:

```
list2 = []

q = int(input('How many contacts would you like to add?: '))
list1 = []
    for i in range(q):
    tempList= []
    name = input('Name: ')
    number = input('Number: ')
    tempList.append(name)
    tempList.append(number)
    list1.append(name)
    list1.append(number)
    list2.append(tempList)

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Output:

> ['abc', '123', 'def', '456', 'ghi', '789']
>
> [['abc', '123'], ['def', '456'], ['ghi', '789']]

Answer (score 0):

It gets overwritten because each time list1 gets reset in each iteration.
Try this one :

```
list2 = []
q = int(input("Quantos contatos deseja adicionar? "))
list1 = []
for i in range(q):
    list3 = []
    nome = list1.append(input("Nome: "))
    num = list1.append(input("Número: "))
    list3 = list1[(i*2):]
    list2.append(list3)

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

This gives expected output that you mentioned.